# Is it appropriate to add vectors from different coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems

Assume a $X_{W}Y_{W}Z_{W}$ orthogonal coordinate system is transformed to an arbitrary
orthogonal system $X_{C}Y_{C}Z_{C}$ by a 3D transformation matrix M, where M is represented by
4x4 matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & t_x \\
d & e & f & t_y \\
g & h & i & t_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$O_{W}$ is the origin of $X_{W}Y_{W}Z_{W}$ and $O_{C}$ is the origin of $X_{C}Y_{C}Z_{C}$.

Given an arbitrary point P in the space. It's coordinates in $X_{W}Y_{W}Z_{W}$ is $(x_{w}, y_{w}, z_{w})$, while in $X_{C}Y_{C}Z_{C}$ is $(x_{c}, y_{c}, z_{c})$. The coordinates of $O_{C}$ in $X_{W}Y_{W}Z_{W}$ is $(x, y, z)$.

I wonder does the relation $\overrightarrow{O_WP} = \overrightarrow{O_WO_C} + \overrightarrow{O_CP}$ hold? It seems that $\overrightarrow{O_WO_C}$ and $\overrightarrow{O_CP}$ are in different coordinates and the coordinates unit may change.

If so, is it possible to add vectors like $\overrightarrow{O_WO_C}$ in $X_{W}Y_{W}Z_{W}$ with vectors like $\overrightarrow{O_CP}$ in $X_{C}Y_{C}Z_{C}$, or mathmatically, can we derive

$$
x_{w} = x_{c} + x \\
y_{w} = y_{c} + y \\
z_{w} = z_{c} + z
$$

from $(x_{w}, y_{w}, z_{w}) = (x_{c}, y_{c}, z_{c}) + (x, y, z)$ ?

If matrix M is only a translation matrix, I think the relation holds. But I'm not sure about an arbitrary transformation.

[image]

Comment: Every vector has a set of coordinates in every basis. If the transformation is a pure translation, the basis vectors are the same and therefore so are the coordinates of the vector in each basis. If the transformation includes a non-trivial rotation, a vector may have different coordinates in different bases. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DavidKd I don't get the point what is a non-trivial rotation, I know 3D transformation mostly based on computer graphic, for example [3D Geometric Transformation](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~dcor/Graphics/cg-slides/geom3d.pdf). I have knowledge about translation, scaling, shearing and rotation. I understand a pure translation doesn't change basis vectors according to your comment. But I am still confused with a pure scaling, shearing or rotation.

Comment: A rotation by zero degrees or $360$ degrees would be a trivial rotation: "trivial" because it doesn't actually do anything. I didn't realize we were dealing with transformations that don't preserve distances. If the transformation is in the form \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 & t_x \\
0 & 1 &0 & t_y \\
0 & 0 &1 & t_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} then all vectors have the same coordinates. Otherwise there will be vectors whose coordinates change.

Comment: @DavidK I don't quite get 'deal with transformations that don't preserve distances', what effect does 'preserve distances' have here? I know rigid-body transformation preserves distance, angle and size. Similarity transformation preserves angle. Linear transformation preserves linearity of addition and scalar multiplication. Affine transformation preserves parallel lines. Projective transformation preserves lines. Rotation will keep distance but non-trival rotation will change the basis vector.

Comment: Can I draw the conclusion that: only when transformation is a pure translation, a 0 degree rotation, a 360 degrees rotation or a mix of three, the relation $\overrightarrow{O_WP} = \overrightarrow{O_WO_C} + \overrightarrow{O_CP}$ holds. Other transformations except these four will break the equation. And feel free to post your comment as answer as I can accpet it.